# Custom labels for UserProfileForm in Django

Tags: django, django-models, user-profile

I'm using the UserProfileForm class under django.db to take the UserProfile model class and turn it into a form. Currently, the labels for the form elements are the column names of the underlying db table. I'm wondering if there is a way that I can customize the labels?

Thanks,
Tino

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean a model form using django.forms.ModelForm.  You can add a verbose name to your UserProfileModel, or you can use the label arg in your ModelForm like so:

```
>>> class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
...     pub_date = DateField(label='Publication date')
...
...     class Meta:
...         model = Article
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/